# Странный пробел между лайками.

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, друзья, у меня к Вам такой вопрос: я делал свой первый сайт, ну вроде как все путем, вы мне помогли в моем предыдущем вопросе и я был очень рад. Скажите, не могли бы вы еще раз посетить мой сайт http://celldweller.org/ и сказать мне почему происходит следующая вещь:
На главной странице сайта, слева меню, а под текстом стоят лайки от трех социальных сетей, так вот если в меню добавить новый пункт, то пустое пространство между лайками от фэйсбука, Г+1 и вконтакте автоматически увеличивается, причем это происходит в независимости от того вставляю я туда просто ссылку на страницу или плеер как это сделано сейчас. В чем может заключаться проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вёрстка у тебя хреноватая, сразу сказать не могу, могу только сказать что изменяется высота основного блока вроде изза блока меню, убери лишнее и сделай чтобы они не связаны были, например

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="left_menu">
  </div>
  <div id="main_text">
  </div>
</div>
```

и тут например задай position:relative для content в css, а для остальных(left_menu и main_text) position:absolute и у main_text left:260px; или скок у тебя там